# What does clustering algorithms do with missing data?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, missing-data

I wonder in clustering, what does algorithms like KMeans do with missing value data? For example, if in one of our samples, the information for one of the dimensions is NaN, what KMeans do with that dimension when compare it to others? Does it give a value like average of others or just ignore this dimension when comparing to other samples? What is best strategy?

Comment: Usually it just drops rows with any missing data.

Comment: Yes, I meant missing values. I just did not remember correct word for it.

Comment: About dropping, you mean that e.g. if our example x is of1000 dimension and only one is missing i.e. x has 999 dimension of information, it still will be dropped?

Comment: @user2974951 means *listwise* deletion, dropping from analysis the entirety of the information for the row of data containing the NANs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder in clustering, what does algorithms like KMeans do with missing value data? [...]

They do the same as all the other algorithms, that is, *nothing*. All the machine learning algorithms are designed to work with numerical data. They do mathematical operations on it, split the data on the values (decision trees), calculate distances ($k$NN), etc. Those operations are not possible when a value is absent.

But you seem to be confusing the algorithms with their implementations. An algorithm can have many different implementations, in different programming languages. The implementations can decide to handle missing data in some way, but that's the decision of their developers. To learn what a particular implementation does, you need to refer to its documentation and/or source code if it is available.

> Does it give a value like average of others or just ignore this dimension when comparing to other samples [...]

It can do many things. It can throw an error, drop a row that contains a missing value, it can replace the missing value with something (e.g. average from the non-missing rows), it can treat the missing value as a separate value (e.g. decision tree splitting on "missing vs not"), etc. To learn more about different approaches check other questions tagged as [missing-data](/questions/tagged/missing-data).

> What is best strategy?

There's no best strategy. It's a matter of cost-benefits for a particular problem. For example, if you are removing rows that have missing values you are removing data that may be useful. If you are replacing the values with something, you are possibly biasing your data, which can lead to garbage results, etc.

*Now, putting my developer hat on,* personally I would say, and many would agree, that the best implementation can do is to throw an error so that the user is aware that their data contains missing data and can decide how to deal with it. By doing this, you [prevent the user from being surprised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) by seeing some strange results because of how the values were handled.

Comment: Specific implementations could use an imputation method before analysis. Better the user do this explicitly. Generally, dropping cases is a poor solution.